# python 3.7 package for nessus 8.4 with documentation

Tags: python, nessus

Trying to create a small python penetration testing toolkit and would like to implement nessus scanner. I don't seem to be able to find a package for the newest nessus 8.4 ( I did find a package for nessus 6 - although not with a python 3.7 support) and cannot seem to be able to figure the tenable io package. Anyone coud help please?

Answer (score 0):

Nessus 6 API works with python3.7 just fine. I am surprised you didn't find the Download page for Nessus so here it is: https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus. It's now on 8.5. It will provide the newest as updates become available. The Scan API dies after Nessus 6 so if you're hoping to automate scanning, you'll be stuck with Nessus 6.